# how to write a simple Python Multi-thread task

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous

I have the below simple functions:

```py
import time

def foo():
    print(f'i am working come back in 5mins')
    time.sleep(300)

def boo():
    print(f' boo!')

def what_ever_function():
    print(f'do whatever function user input at run time.')
```

What I wish to do is execute `foo()` and then immediately execute `boo()` or `what_ever_function()` without having to wait for 300 seconds for `foo()` to finish.

Imagine a workflow in Ipython:

```py
>>> foo()
i am working come back in 5mins
>>> boo()
boo!
```

The idea is after execute `foo()`, I can use the user-prompt to run another function immediately; whatever function that may be; without having to wait 300 seconds for `foo()` to finish.

I already tried googleing:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html
and
https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#

But still couldn't achieve the above task.

Any pointer or help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use asyncio, you should use `asyncio.sleep` instead of `time.sleep` because it would block the asycio event loop. here is a working example:

```py
import asyncio


async def foo():
    print("Waiting...")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("Done waiting!")


async def bar():
    print("Hello, world!")


async def main():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(foo())
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(bar())

    await t1, t2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

In this example, `foo` and `bar` run concurrently: `bar` does execute while `foo` also do.

Comment: thank you Louis!!!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Consider upvoting or accepting the answer if it answered your question.